# How to make a continuous scroll with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slider

I have [this site I am developing](http://www.clients.eirestudio.net/chris/test/Site/) - I made the scroller with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
      function scrollIt()
      {
         $('#featured-brands div#scroll').animate({
            marginLeft: "-4550px"}, 85000, "linear").animate({ 
               marginTop: "-223px" }, 200, "linear").animate({ 
                  marginLeft: "750px" }, 100, "linear").animate({ 
                 marginTop: "57px" }, 1, "linear", scrollIt);
      }
      scrollIt();
});
```

When the final image is sliding across, there is a white blank space visible, how would I make the first image appear right after the final image, so there is no white space?

Cheers,
Keith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

split it into two. When one goes off the bottom, move it so it's above the other.

Comment: I made a demo. I left off the clipping (you can imagine the black rectangle clipping) so you can see how it works: http://jasonwoof.com/downloads/scroll_demo.html